# How to convert array of comma delimited values to array with unique values?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of comma delimited properties:

- Red,Green
- Green
- Blue,Black
- Yellow
- Red,Black

Now I'd like to extract every unique colour from the array resulting in the following list:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Black
- Yellow

Since I'm extracting the information from a database with Entity Framework in quite a complex structure I'd like to do the conversion in one statement if possible.

Comment: Split on the commas, merge all the values into one list and do a `Distinct()` on it, perhaps?

Comment: I haven't tried very many things since I just didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your array of properties is like:

```
string[] properties = {"Red,Green","Green","Blue,Black","Yellow","Red,Black"};
```

you should split on comma and select the distinct values in this way:

```
string[] unique = properties.SelectMany(x=>x.Split(',')).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, that works with a simple array. Thank you. Unfortunately that does not work with Entity Framework and SQL Server. I get an error saying `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' `

Comment: Just call `ToArray()` before the `SelectMany`